# corelocation keeps looping

Tags: ios, core-location, infinite-loop

I essentially started off with this CoreLocation iOS tutorial to get my head around how to implement CoreLocation into my app. (http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_Location_Application)

But what I have encountered when trying to incorporate this tutorial into my app is that it now just keeps on looping over and over, which is just baffling me. Can anyone please help?

GPSViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface GPSViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *startLocation;
@end
```

GPSViewController.m

```
#import "GPSViewController.h"

#import "DataClass.h"

@interface GPSViewController ()

@end

@implementation GPSViewController
@synthesize locationManager, startLocation;

DataClass *obj;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //initialization og global varable.
    DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];

    //GPS Initialise
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    startLocation = nil;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSString *currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%g",
                                 newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    //latitude.text = currentLatitude;
    obj.Latatude = currentLatitude;

    NSString *currentLongitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithFormat:@"%g",
                                  newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    //longitude.text = currentLongitude;
    obj.Longitude = currentLongitude;

    NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
          newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
          newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    if(obj.Latatude != NULL && obj.Longitude != NULL){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GPSSuccess" sender:self];
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.startLocation = nil;
    self.locationManager = nil;
}


@end
```

Comment: by looping do you mean its calling didUpdateToLocation again and again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` in order to stop it from getting the user's location over and over.

Comment: Ah yes I did try this but it was stopping the program from obtaining the GPS location prior to stopping, but I simply added the [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; on the line above [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GPSSuccess" sender:self]; and it still allowed me to obtain the details I desired without the looping issue. Thank you very much.